# How do i create a looping local notification when the user doesn't choose a starting date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localnotification

In my application, the user chooses a day (monday-sunday) to set an alarm for and the application sets up a local notification to repeat weekly on this day. How can i get my application to create a looping weekly notification for this day of the week every week?

Answer (score 1):

Use EventKit to [create a recurring event](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/CreatingRecurringEvents/CreatingRecurringEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH3-SW1).